# Do Spells that cause Status Effects have any effect against Bosses?

Tags: nintendo-ds, final-fantasy-3

I've tried to cast Spells like Blind and Poison multiple times against Boss enemies, yet they always miss.  Can these Bosses even be effected by these Spells?

Comment: depends on the boss in question.

Comment: Are you sure that you've tagged this question correctly?  What platform are you playing on ?  The versions of FF tags can be confusing - please have a look at the tag details.  Also, which bosses?

Comment: Like @KatieK says, are you talking about FF3 (originally Japanese only for the NES) or FF3 (the US numbering, which is the one originally for the SNES and has Terra and Locke and Mog and so forth)?

Comment: @KatieK Final Fantasy 3 DS, the original Japanese game that was released for the first time in America as a remake for the DS.  As for Bosses, nearly every one up until Hein's Castle.  I tried status spells on nearly all the bosses and they all missed.

Comment: D'oh, I was hoping FF6j :(

Comment: @jumpnett - Just checking!  I thought I was the only one who played that game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally Final Fantasy bosses are immune to most negative status effects with specific exceptions (slow being a common-ish one).

Browsing through the [final fantasy wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Ahriman_%28Final_Fantasy_III%29) I don't even see a reference to specific immunities for FF3 bosses (most other games note immunity piecemeal when relevant), so I'd say that's a good hint they're just all immune.

Generally trying to use status effects on bosses is a waste in FF anyway, unless you're aware of a strategy that calls for a status a boss is known to be weak to (or, rarely, if an in-game character suggests their weakness).

Comment: Then what's the point of status spells anyways?  It's not like I ever need them in non-boss battles (unless the enemies get harder or need more strategy compared to your characters level later on in the game).

Comment: @jumpnett strong normal enemies, usually. Status effects are often less useful than direct attack spells, they're only helpful in rare circumstances...which aren't obvious. There's a reason I rarely use status magic in Final Fantasy and I rarely keep status effect moves on my Pokemon...

Comment: Status effect magic has been pretty much useless, outside of corner cases, in every game before XIII, yeah.  (It's pretty damned useful in that one, though.)

Comment: @Shinrai FF8 made it rather useful with Junctions (and Doomtrain), and any game where you could get a weapon with Death as a side effect. But other than that...

Comment: Attacking certain bosses in FF7 to give them a poisoned status or stop is extremely useful.